# How can I stop sapply dropping my barplot titles?

Tags: r, plot, apply, title

I'm wanting to make a barplot for the factor variables in my data set. To do this I've been running `sapply(data[sapply(data, class)=='factor'],function(x) barplot(table(x)))`. To my annoyance, the plots remember their factor labels, but none of them have retained a title. How can I fix this without titling each graph by hand?

Currently, I'm getting humorously vague untitled graphs like this:[image]

Comment: You should include some of your data using `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))` if there is a lot of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
## extract names
fvars <- names(data)[which(sapply(data,inherits,"factor"))]
## apply barplot() with main=
lapply(fvars, function(x) barplot(table(data[[x]]), main=x))
```

?

Example data:

```
data <- mtcars
for (i in c("vs","am","gear","carb")) data[[i]] <- factor(data[[i]])
```

Note that this creates all the plots at once. If you're working in a GUI with a plot history (RStudio or RGui) you can page back through the graphs. Otherwise, you might want to use `par(mfrow=c(nr,nc))` (fill in number of rows and columns) to set up subplots before you start.

The numbers that are returned are the bar midpoints (see `?barplot`): you could wrap the `barplot()` call in `invisible()` if you don't want to see them.

Comment: thanks for the missing bracket. As far as how it behaves: can you provide a [mcve] I can try it out with?